# Do I have a raid or not?

Tags: raid

I am building a new (power) system.  MOBO is a ASUS Sabertooth 990FX.  I've installed:

- 1 500GB HD for the OS and user accounts (mounted at /)
- Three 2TB drive set up on the BIOS as a single raid0 (mounted at /raid)

The issues is that I cannot confirm the size of the raid from the mount point.  When I look at the properties of /raid it tells me `free space:  unknown`.  I am unsure of the output I'm getting from `fdisk -l` as this is my first foray into raid.

`fdisk` is inconclusive and `cat /proc/meminfo` appears to indicate that I'm not getting the memory I expect (see below!).

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Bruce

*********************** `fdisk -l` output:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009a55f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1             384  3095388671  1547694144   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2      3095389054  3128815103    16713025    5  Extended

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdd: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bc319

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *     2152710   976768064   487307677+  83  Linux
/dev/sdd2             124     2152709     1076293    5  Extended
/dev/sdd5             126     2152709     1076292   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/pdc_beejhachf: 1602.0 GB, 1601953333248 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 194759 cylinders, total 3128815104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 196608 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009a55f

                    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/pdc_beejhachf1             384  3095388671  1547694144   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/mapper/pdc_beejhachf2      3095389054  3128815103    16713025    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/pdc_beejhachf5      3095389056  3128815103    16713024   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/mapper/pdc_beejhachf1: 1584.8 GB, 1584838803456 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 192679 cylinders, total 3095388288 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 196608 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/pdc_beejhachf1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/pdc_beejhachf5: 17.1 GB, 17114136576 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2080 cylinders, total 33426048 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 196608 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/pdc_beejhachf5 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

************************ `cat /proc/meminfo` output

```
MemTotal:       16405964 kB
MemFree:        14722300 kB
Buffers:           64496 kB
Cached:           709308 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           886560 kB
Inactive:         391952 kB
Active(anon):     505508 kB
Inactive(anon):      712 kB
Active(file):     381052 kB
Inactive(file):   391240 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      16713020 kB
SwapFree:       16713020 kB
Dirty:               552 kB
Writeback:           388 kB
AnonPages:        504664 kB
Mapped:           197904 kB
Shmem:              1512 kB
Slab:              96652 kB
SReclaimable:      72460 kB
SUnreclaim:        24192 kB
KernelStack:        2904 kB
PageTables:        21804 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24916000 kB
Committed_AS:    2080264 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      334800 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359391644 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      138240 kB
DirectMap2M:     4005888 kB
DirectMap1G:    12582912 kB
```

**************************** `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo` output

```
MemTotal:       16405964 kB
```

Answer (score 2):

You have [Fake RAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto).

Rule of thumb is that unless you spent hundreds of dollars on a RAID device, you don't have hardware RAID. In many situations, software RAID is preferable to hardware RAID, so that's not a problem. However, you'd probably be happier with real linux software raid (md)

Comment: Okay, so the basic steps involved would be?  (1) Remove raid setting from bios (2) use rmraid to set up the software raid?

Comment: use *mdadm* to set up software raid. This can also be done from the alternate CD's installer.